# Installing Ubuntu on Compaq Presario CQ 5210

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, lts, compaq, presario

I am trying to see if I can install Ubuntu 18.04 (or any other LTS version) in my old Compaq desktop. Here are the specs of the computer:

https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c01859813

I went through the Ubuntu hardware certified website

(https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?query=&category=Desktop&level=&vendors=HP)

There was nothing on that website on Compaq, and when checking the HP computers, there were very few and none had the same motherboard as my desktop

I also installed a GT 730 (GPU) but that is a side question

Thank you for any help anyone can provide about this

Answer (score 0):

Not all manufacturers certify all of their hardware for Ubuntu, and often only do so for machines likely used by developers.

http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours lists several Ubuntu derivatives which are LTS and are supported here, yet which are less demanding than the standard Ubuntu which uses the demanding GNOME3  desktop. A review of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) over a double-double and a box of TimBits will provide some useful background.